# Google map is not updated against touch action (zoom plus, minus, pinch in out,...)

Tags: google-maps

I am developing android app showing google map with my track record markers. It works OK only showing first with good scaling and positioning.

But pinching and any other action does not update(redraw) the google map.

Even pressing +/- button on Zoom control, map zoom in,out is detected but no map is updated. Only map shown first time is physically magnified. No map updated is done. Scrolling to right shows blank map only.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    . . .

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    . . .
```

Anything I should consider more action when zoomed +/- or to activate pinching, move to right or left?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer within the log trace.
google api key I gave was old, and this new application use google api v2 and I needed to get new key.